# Exercise with zeros of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Determine if it is possible, for an entire function $f$, to vanish in the points $\{ \log k +i\log h : h,k \in \mathbb Z^+ \}$, and to have finite growth order.

Weierstrass' theroem about infinite products states there is an entire function $f$ vanishing in $\{ \log k +i\log h : h,k \in \mathbb Z^+ \}$, because, as $k,h$ increase, $|\log k +i\log h|$ goes to infinity. However I don't see how to prove that $f$ has finite growth order; I also know Hadamard's factorization theorem, but it doesn't seem to be useful because the finite order is in the hypothesis of the theorem, not in the thesis. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you have to count how many zeroes are in a disc - finite order imposes a constraint of the type $R^C$ where $C$ is essentially the order (up to exponential terms and $\epsilon$; bottom line is that many zeroes imply high order (eg $\sin \pi z$ has roughly $2N$ zeroes in radius $N$ so has order $1$, but $\sin \pi z^2$ has roughly $2N^2$ in radius $N$ so has order $2$ - in your case you may have too many zeroes for finite order

Comment: Thank you, you're right. In our case the number of zeros in a disk $D_R(0)$ is exactly $2e^R$, if $R$ is natural. Clearly as $R\to \infty $ there are no $C, \rho \in \mathbb R^+ $ such that $2e^R\le CR^\rho$, so the order is not finite

Comment: looked like that to me at a glance - happy to help